# migrating url alias from drupal6 to drupal7 as a part of migration process

Tags: drupal, migration

I have migrated nodes using migrate module v2. Currently i am running into a problem that the previous site used url aliases,which have not been migrated into drupal7 and will affect the site rank from SEO perspective.

Is there a way i can migrate the path aliases while running the migration classes itself?If not what would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way (according to me) to have the same url aliases is :

1> install url_alias module.

2> configure the nodes with patterns similar to drupal6. Now, this step may trouble you, in case the new url-aliases have nids attached to them.(as in my case).

As a solution we can go ahead and create custom tokens using code where the source id can be fetched from the migrate map tables based on the new destination ids which are easily available.

Now, we can go ahead and bulk generate url-aliases.

An example for creating such custom token would be:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function custom_configuration_token_info() {  
  $type = array(
    'node' => array (
      'name' => t('Nodes'), 
      'description' => t('Tokens related to individual nodes.'), 
      'needs-data' => 'node',
     ),

         'term' => array(
           'name' => t('Taxonomy Terms'),
           'description' => t('Tokens related to taxonomy terms.'),
           'needs-data' => 'term',
         )
      );

      // tokens for node legacy nid.
      $tokens['node']['mapid'] = array(
        'name' => t("mapid"), 
        'description' => t("The nid of the node prior to migration."),
      );

      $tokens['term']['mapid'] = array(
        'name' => t('mapid'),
        'description' => t('The tid of taxonomy terms prior to migration.'),
      );

      return array(
        'types' => $type, 
        'tokens' => $tokens,
      );
    }


    now,

    function custom_configuration_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
      $url_options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
      if (isset($options['language'])) {
        $url_options['language'] = $options['language'];
        $language_code = $options['language']->language;
      }
      else {
        $language_code = NULL;
      }
      $sanitize = !empty($options['sanitize']);

      $replacements = array();

      if ($type == 'node' && !empty($data['node'])) {
        $node = $data['node'];

        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
              switch ($name) {

    <write your custom code for the token conditioned by the name attribute in info function>

        }
      }
    }
```

While writing your custom code, you mite also be needing the legacy table. Drupal 7 supports multiple databases, so just configure the legacy table credentials in settings.php file.

Use drupal_set_active while fetching data from the different tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can migrate your legacy aliases directly into the Drupal 7 path field:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('path', 'my_legacy_alias_field');
```

Comment: There is no field in Drupal 6 that keeps that information on the node? I believe you need to map that to the "path" field on prepareRow() by querying the url_aliase table [select * from url_alias where src = 'node/123';] - OR am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: My original answer was the general case - for Drupal-to-Drupal migrations, yes, you need to query the url_alias table to obtain the legacy alias. Note that shortly after the original answer I released the migrate_d2d (Drupal-to-Drupal migration) module, which has this built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very stripped down **migration class** that includes an easy method for bringing URLs along for the ride. Intended for use with the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module.

```
class MyNodeMigration extends Migration {
  public function __construct(array $arguments) {
    $this->arguments = $arguments;
    parent::__construct();
    $source_fields = array('nid' => t('The node ID of the page'));

    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')
      ->select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n');
    $query->join('url_alias', 'a', "a.src = CONCAT('node/', n.nid)");
    $query->addField('a', 'dst');
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, $source_fields);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('my_node_type');
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array('nid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'D6 Unique Node ID',
        'alias' => 'n',
      )),
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );

    $this->addSimpleMappings(array('title', 'created', 'changed', 'status'));
    $this->addUnmigratedDestinations(array('sticky', 'log', 'nid'));
    $this->addFieldMapping('path', 'dst');
    $this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the `url_alias`table is globally the same, expect the name of fields whom changed from `src`to `source`and `dst` to `alias`. So I guess you can easily copy the content from your Drupal 6 to your Drupal 7.

I never tried, but in theory it should work.